# Proving angle equality in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABDC$ be a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle with centre $O$. If the diagonals $AD$ and $BC$ intersect at point $E$, then we have to prove that sum of angles $AOB$ and $COD$ is equal to twice angle $AEB$.

It obviously has everything to do with the inscribed angle theorem. But the figure becmes very messy once I draw it. I figured that  if we omit the sides of the quadrilateral ,the theorem would still remain the same. But I cannot see where to start. For now I only want a hint on where to start.Unfortunately I have no good work to show to you guys.

Comment: if you talk of a quadrilateral $\,ABCD\,$ , it is customary to refer to the vertices in *that* order, and thus the diagonals are $\,AC\,,\,BD\,$ and not what you wrote. Please do check this and either tell us what's the order of the vertices or correct your question

Comment: @DonAntonio,Order of vertices :ABDC (clockwise)

Comment: Ok @rahul, thanks. That doesn't make any sense whatsoever in what I'm used to do, **but** perhaps it is so designed as to remark to students not to get used to these or those names.

Comment: @DonAntonio,you should be thanking me for not putting in the original question.It took me a few minutes before I could understand anything.That would be an ideal example to show to students what not to get used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- $|\angle AOB| = 2 |\angle ACB|$, $|\angle COD| = 2|\angle CAD|$,
- $|\angle AEC| + |\angle ECA| + |\angle CAE| = \pi$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: E is the point of intersection of two diagonals.The latter point does not seem to make sense.

Comment: @rahul I missed that you switched names of $C$ and $D$, i.e. your quadrilateral is $ABDC$, not the usual $ABCD$ (fixed). Such naming isn't wrong, but I would advise you against it, it's easy to make mistakes (e.g. as I did).

Comment: We add the two equations on your first hint and get angles AOB+COD=2(ACB+CAD).But of course ,since CB is a straight line ,angle AEB =ACB+CAD,thus conpleting the proof.Thought I'd come back and complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

By the [theorem about the angle of two crossing cords in a circle](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/angles-of-intersecting-chords-theorem.php) , we have that

$$\angle AEB=\frac12\left(\widehat{AB}+\widehat{CD}\right)$$

On the other hand, by definition of central angle:

$$\angle AOB=\widehat{AB}\;,\;\;\;\angle COD=\widehat{CD}$$

Well, there you are! And note that the inscribed angles theorem plays no role win this demonstration.